TeamCity Dependency Resolve on Base-Branches
I am currently facing the following problem, there is a multi-repository structure with 2 repositories, A and B.
For building B we need to build A first as a dependency. Additionally, when changes to A are pushed, it will use forward compilation to compile and execute tests on B to check that everything still runs well. In general it works very well with TC. But once feature branches come into play there is the following issue.
Assume both repositories A and B have a feature branch dev/featureA that introduce some breaking changes.
Now if there is another branch for A - dev/featureA/bugfix the issue is that now TeamCity will try to forward compile also repository B but will use the default branch for that, which will fail, because the changes of dev/featureA are necessary.
Is there a possibility to configure TeamCity to not only try find a branch with the same name on a dependent repository but if it does not find one, try to get the base-branch (which in the example above would be dev/featureA) to compile correctly?
Thank you in advance

What do you call a "forward compilation"? Do your A and B build configurations use the same VCS root? Do they have a Snapshot Dependency link configured between them?

What i mean is that while B depends on A a push to A will also cause B to build to check if any changes to code in A would break B.
A and B are 2 different repositories but in the same organisation on Github.
The snapshot dependency is configured but it seems to be only able to match branches based on exact name match and will default on development if there are no two matching names.
